# Java method stops being called

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Tomcat server running a large application. It has two classes similar to this example:

```
public abstract class ClassA {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassA.class);
  // ...
  public File methodA(ICancellable cancel) {
    URL request = new URL("an URL");
    LOGGER.debug("Calling ClassB.methodB(type)");
    File f = classB.methodB(request, "type", cancel);
    LOGGER.debug("The call to ClassB.methodB(type)"
                 + " returned the File==" + f);
    // ...
  }
}

public class ClassB {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClassB.class);
  // ...
  public static synchronized File methodB(URL url, String type, 
                                          ICancellable cancel) 
  {
    final String thisMethodsName = "ClassB.methodB(url: " + url 
                           + ", type:" + type + ", cancel: " + cancel + ")";
    LOGGER.debug("Entering method: " + thisMethodsName);
    // ...
    return f;
  }
}
```

The application works properly, and `ClassA.methodA()` initially calls succesfully to `ClassB.methodB()`, as I can see in the log files:

```
[...]
14/02/2013 12:34:56 DEBUG ClassA:123 - Calling ClassB.methodB(type)
14/02/2013 12:34:56 DEBUG ClassB:456 - Entering method: ClassB.methodB(url: anURL, type: type, cancel: @1234);
[...]
14/02/2013 12:34:56 DEBUG ClassA:125 - The call to ClassB.methodB(type) returned the File=="aFile".
[...]
```

My problem is after the server is working for some time, it stops calling `ClassB.methodB()`. the application gets hung and it simply writes this to the log:

```
[...]
14/02/2013 12:34:56 DEBUG ClassA:123 - Calling ClassB.methodB(type)
```

That's the last line of the log file. `ClassB.methodB()` isn't actually called.

I suspected it could be due to opened resources that werent closed, but I'm trying to locate all the code that did that, and after fixsing so, it still happens.

What can be causing this? How can I continue searching for the cause?

---

JVM version: 1.6.0_13
Tomcat version: 6.0.18

Comment: I assume may be in extreme cases when the file gets REALLY huge (i.e. GB+), it take more time to append to it.

Comment: Have you checked that the previous call to `ClassB.methodB` has actually finished?

Comment: The downloaded file is not larger than similar (or even the same) file downloaded the times it works.
Anyway, I've waited several hours and the application still does nothing.

Comment: @Qwerky Actually I have **not** checked that **all** the previously calls to `ClassB.methodB` have finished. I'll take a peek in the log file.

Comment: Are there no other stack traces?

Comment: It appears that ClassA.methodA wasn't called either. Have you checked that it should be?

Comment: @aksappy No. When it hangs the last line is the shown in the second log example. (Sorry: I have to fix it. It should say `Calling ClassB.methodB(type)`.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. its a static sync method, only the last call may ever be not finished.

Comment: Have you checked whether there are any interdependent/deadlock method calls?

Comment: @aksappy No, I havn't. How can I do (or learn how to do) so?

Comment: Moving to answer for potential points :D

Comment: I've found about 5 LOG lines like `Calling ClassB.methodB(type)` that weren't followed by `The call to ClassB.methodB(type) returned the File=="aFile".` Until I made this question I had only noticed the last (hanging) one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that there is a thread deadlock bug involving some code that you didn't paste? Your `ClassB.methodB` method is `synchronized`. You probably have some other thread that is holding and not releasing the `synchronized` lock on `ClassB.class`, preventing the thread that is doing the logging from ever acquiring that lock and entering the method.

Comment: `ClassB.methodB` was creating a third thread (let's call it *thread3*), and waiting for that thread to finish. It never happened, as was waiting for an InputStream which never was granted. So *thread1* was in `ClassB.methodB` waiting for *thread3* to finish. As it never happened, *thread1* never left the synchronized method, so *threa2* calling from `ClassA.methodA` could never enter in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable the debug mode and assign breakpoints in your code. Use IDE ( preferrably eclipse) to go step by step.
2. Eclipse has plugins like findbugs or PMD to scan the code and find out possible bugs.
3. Manually go through every conditions, method calls, loops to see flaws.

If you have written the complete app, then you would know where to look at. If not, it would still be good to check all that is written

Comment: The error didn't happen in my development machine, only when running in a server. With this certain development environment, I can't debug this problem in a development station, as they have no access to internet and the downloaded files must come from internet servers.